# toggle element by numerical value of data attribute in django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I have a list of group names and for each group name i have a list of students names.
I want to show the list of names under each group on the click of group name.

for eg.

```
group 1(#clicked)     
    A 
    B
    C
group 2(#not clicked)
group 3(#clicked)
    F
    E
    R
```

I have two models

1: Groups(id,name)
2: Students(id,name,group_id)

HTML:-

```
{% for group in groups%}
<span class="group-list" data-id="{{group.id}}">{{group.name}}<span class="clickSpan">Click To Expand</span><span class="date">Group created Date:{{group.update_date}}</span></span>
    <div class="child name-list">
    {% for stu in group.students_set.all %}
    <span>{{stu.name}}</span>
{%endfor%}
</div>
{%endfor%}
```

I want to send group id as attribute and use it to dispaly only those names which match the group_id.
My Html gives me correct names under each group. All i want is to toggle them on click of group name.Right now it toggles all the names under all the groups.

EDIT:
JAVASCRIPT:

```
nameDisplay = function () {
    $(".clickSpan").click(function () {
        $(".group-list").next('.name-list').toggle()
    });
}
```

clickSpan is the class of the span that i added against each group name which says "click to exapnd". How will i be able to achieve the same target with this?
Also it will be better if i can get "click to collapse" here when it is expanded.

Comment: Where is elements with these `students-list`, `class-list` and `name-list` CSS class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your markup the `group-list` element and the `name-list` that has to be toggled are sibling elements so you can make use of that relationship to toggle the correct element.

There is no need to have another attribute to do that.

```
nameDisplay = function () {
    $(".name-list").hide();
    $(".group-list").click(function () {
        $(this).next('.name-list').toggle()
    });
}
```

---

Also it will be better to use a css rule to set the default hidden state of `name-list` like

```
.name-list {
    display: none;
}
```

then use the click handler to make it visible

```
nameDisplay = function () {
    $(".group-list").click(function () {
        $(this).next('.name-list').toggle()
    });
}
```

Comment: great.thnx for the help sir.

Comment: I have edited my question. regarding click to expand and click to collapse span. can you please help me with this.

Comment: @FullOfQuestions can you share the html for `clickSpan`

Comment: @FullOfQuestions `$(this).parent().next('.name-list').toggle()`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/), or other methods to traverse using the element for which event is triggered then can use `.toggle()` method

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

```
$(".group-list").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".name-list").toggle();
});
```

There is no need for additional attribute.